# Assign the drive letter (/dev/sdb) manually

Tags: server, mount, hard-drive, automatic

I have an old computer, I installed Ubuntu Server 20.04, it works perfectly but it changes the letter it assigns to the hard drives every time I start it and it deconfigures the automatic mounting. It has 5 hard drives.

Is there a way to fix the letter, so that when starting it does not change?

Example; /dev/sd(a) or whatever.

Stay tuned, greetings!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to fix this is to not use the device name (/dev/sdb) to mount it but instead use the UUID.   Check /dev/disk/by*/ for your drive's uuid.  (There are several other ways to get it as well.)   Then instead of the device name, use `UUID=` followed by what you find.

Comment: This answer could be enhanced by a link to instructions.